# Locating row by value in multiple columns

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, rows

This is my DataFrame (df):
[image]

i want to iterate over my rows, and if i see a '999' value somewhere (id excluded):

1. I need to make sure the entire row is '999'.
2. I need to make sure the 2nd row that has the same id value is also covered with '999's.

for example, for id=5, i have a row with 999 in it, and the second row where id=5 does not have '999's.

Expected output:
[image]

this is what i have:

```
num_of_p = len(df.columns) - 1
for v in df.index:
    if (sum(df.iloc[v] == 999) != num_of_p):
        if (sum(df.iloc[v] == 999) != 0):
          raise Exception("***** value 999 should apply to the entire row -please check and re-run*****")
```

and this code works for my first condition.
I'm having trouble figuring the second one.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? There is only one row with all 999

Comment: @Erfan I updated with my expected output. if there's a row with even a single '999', it should all be '999' and also the second row with the same id number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```py
m = df.loc[:, "p1":].apply(lambda x: 999 in x.values, axis=1)
df.loc[df["id"].isin(df.loc[m, "id"]), "p1":] = 999
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id   p1   p2   p3   p4
0   2    0    0    0    0
1   2    1    1    1    1
2   4  999  999  999  999
3   4  999  999  999  999
4   5  999  999  999  999
5   5  999  999  999  999
6   9    1    1    1    1
7   9    0    0    0    0
```

---

EDIT: To get single "rows" that contains 999 (assuming there are always twins):

```py
m = df.loc[:, "p1":].apply(lambda x: 999 in x.values, axis=1)

x = df.loc[m, "id"].value_counts()
print('Rows that contain 999 and are "single":')
print(x[x == 1].index.values)
```

Prints:

```
Rows that contain 999 and are "single":
[5]
```

Comment: thanks for that. what would you write instead in order to not change the table? i just want to know if these conditions are true..

Comment: @HavingNoHead Do you want to know if there's 999 in any row? The mask `m` contains `True` on these rows.

Comment: i already managed to determine if there's a 999 in a row and not the whole row. what i need right now is to know wether a row has 999 in it and her "twin" row (same id number) does not..

Comment: thanks for ur time, but i dont think i follow. is 5 the row number or occurences? either way its not right i think.. there are 2 line with single 999's.. i managed to determine if they are indeed single, now i want only to know if the "twin" row of a row that has 999 in it, also contains 999's.

Comment: @HavingNoHead No, `5` is ID of the row that has twin row with `999` and there is one row with `id=5` without `999`

Comment: Got it, ur the best.